# Change structure of Woocommerce products page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a wordpress site that is working with the woocommerce plugin.
This is what I am having trouble with:

**IN SHORT:**
In the main products page, the product description is part of the anchor and is therefore clickable. I would like to limit the anchor to only the product name.
How can I achieve this?

**DETAILS:**
The woocommerce product page is structured as follows:

```
        <ul class="products">
        <li class=MULTIPLE_CLASSES>
            <a href="LINK_TO_PRODUCT_PAGE">
                <img class="" etc.....>
                <h3>PRODUCT_NAME</h3>
                <div itemprop="description">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <span class="price">
                    <span class="amount">COST_OF_PRODUCT</span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <a class="button etc..."</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

As such, the anchor is applied to all the product's information, including the description and the price.
I don't really like this functionality and also, as such, the user can't select the text. So I would like the anchor to surround **only the product name**.

I guess the output I want is something like this:

```
        <ul class="products">
        <li class=MULTIPLE_CLASSES>
            <a href="LINK_TO_PRODUCT_PAGE">
                <img class="".....>
                <h3>PRODUCT_NAME</h3>
            </a>
            <div itemprop="description">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <span class="price">
                <span class="amount">COST_OF_PRODUCT</span>
            </span>
            <a class="button ...."</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So far, I tried as follows:

1. Researched on the web to see how to customize woocommerce pages. What I found was to duplicate the file you want to change and put it in the `child-theme/woocommerce` folder. However, that applies only to the files in the `templates` folder, but this file *seems* to be ***not*** in the templates folder but rather in the `includes/admin/views` folder
2. The reason why I italicized the word 'seems' is because I changed that core file manually and replaced it, but it does not take effect! On the site, the structure is still as always! So maybe this is not the file?!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

P.S. I know how to code in many languages, but I never got to PHP. So, if this involves PHP, I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: that is a template file and not admin views... also, this is not the default structure of woocommerce... try changing theme and see if you still have the problem...

Comment: Reigel is right, that's not the default structure of WooCommerce, which means your parent theme is modifying it. And if your `woocommerce/some-file.php` isn't working from your child theme then I would guess that your parent theme is filtering `woocommerce_template_path` to change the default theme template folder from `woocommerce` to something else. Check your theme for that filter and rename your child theme's `woocommerce` folder to match the parent theme's value.

Comment: Hi guys, you're right. The default woocommerce theme does not have the product description at all. I just realized that I had an add_action function in my functions.php file which added it in. I figured out a way to resolve this issue - I have to run now - I will post first thing tomorrow morning. THANKS!

Comment: I have this same issue, though I changed themes to woocommerce storefront to see if all the elements are contained within the <A> attribute and they are…